# Track http reference on https site using fiddler

Tags: http, https, protocols, bug-tracking, fiddler

I have a site `https://mysite.com` which deals with various portlets, gadgets. One of the gadget must be referring to `http` instead of `https`.

I would'nt know which one just by `view source` I want to use fiddler. Can some one explain me how do I use it to track `http` reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  Boot up Fiddler and enabled HTTPS decryption.  Then visit your site and let the page load.  Then look at the Protocol column in Fiddler's main session list.  One of them will say HTTP instead of HTTPS.

Comment: Alternatively, use IE9 and hit F12. Look in the Developer Tools' console window for the exact insecure URL.